# BGL - graph passed to visitor's functions forgetting vertex properties

Tags: c++, boost, graph

I'm trying to implement a bridge-detecting algorithm (tarjan) in BGL by writing a custom DFS-visitor (`class TarjanVisitor : public default_dfs_visitor`) and I'm using a vertex property `parent` to keep track of whence the node was reached.

However, I cannot seem to set vertices' properties during the traversal without resorting to some visitor-global reference.

In my particular case, I have the following in my `tree_edge`:

```
debug_print("setting " << g[trgt].id << "'s parent to " << g[curr].id)
g[trgt].parent = g[curr].id;
debug_print(g[trgt].id << "'s parent is now " << g[trgt].parent)
```

(`debug_print` is just a print that I can turn off by undefining a macro)

then in `discover_vertex`, I have

```
debug_print(g[u].id << "'s parent is " << g[u].parent)
assert(g[u].parent >= 0);
```

and I'm starting the DFS-traversal by setting 1 as root and its `parent` to itself.

```
TarjanVisitor vis = TarjanVisitor();
g[vertex(1,g)].parent = 1;
depth_first_search(g,visitor(vis)
    .root_vertex(vertex(1,g)) //note to self: DOT, not comma
);
```

Here's the (cleaned) debugging output I'm getting:

```
discover_vertex: 1
1's parent is 1
examine_edge: 1 <-> 2
tree_edge: 1 <-> 2
setting 2's parent to 1
2's parent is now 1
discover_vertex: 2
2's parent is -1
Assertion `g[u].parent >= 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Now if instead of using the Graph passed to the individual functions, I'm passing a reference to the Graph to the constructor of the visitor and use that Graph as `g`, the properties are updated as expected, so I can only guess that the problem is that `g` in e.g. `void tree_edge(Edge e, Graph g)` is passed the graph by value and any changes made to it ignored.

Changing to e.g. `void tree_edge(Edge e, Graph& g)` will net me a nice long and absolutely illegible error message about something that is required during the instantiation of `boost::detail::depth_first_visit_impl`.

Is passing a reference to the visitor really the only way to go? Because I kind of refuse to believe I need to pass a graph by value to all functions only to *not* do anything with it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had a brainwave. You said you tried

```
 void tree_edge(Edge e, Graph& g) { ...
```

That will of course not work if the graph is const (and that is like the case due the implementation of dfs in BGL.

Make it const reference!

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/47dc4fdf2bc283a4)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/depth_first_search.hpp>

using namespace boost;

struct MyVertex {};
struct MyEdge   {};

using Graph = adjacency_list<vecS, vecS, directedS, MyVertex, MyEdge>;

struct my_visitor : default_dfs_visitor {
    template <class Vertex, class Graph>
        void initialize_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph& g) { 
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__ << "(" << u << ", g)\n";
            (void) g;
        }
    template <class Vertex, class Graph>
        void start_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph& g) { 
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__  << "(" << u << ", g)\n";
            (void) g;
        }
    template <class Vertex, class Graph>
        void discover_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph& g) { 
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__  << "(" << u << ", g)\n";
            (void) g;
        }
    template <class Edge, class Graph>
        void examine_edge(Edge u, const Graph& g) { 
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__  << "(" << u << ", g)\n";
            (void) g;
        }
    template <class Edge, class Graph>
        void tree_edge(Edge u, const Graph& g) { 
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__  << "(" << u << ", g)\n";
            (void) g;
        }
    template <class Edge, class Graph>
        void back_edge(Edge u, const Graph& g) { 
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__  << "(" << u << ", g)\n";
            (void) g;
        }
    template <class Edge, class Graph>
        void forward_or_cross_edge(Edge u, const Graph& g) { 
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__  << "(" << u << ", g)\n";
            (void) g;
        }
    template <class Edge, class Graph>
        void finish_edge(Edge u, const Graph& g) { 
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__  << "(" << u << ", g)\n";
            (void) g;
        }
    template <class Vertex, class Graph>
        void finish_vertex(Vertex u, const Graph& g) { 
            std::cout << __FUNCTION__  << "(" << u << ", g)\n";
            (void) g;
        }
};

#include <random>
#include <boost/graph/random.hpp>

int main() {
    Graph g;

    std::mt19937 prng {42};
    generate_random_graph(g, 10, 20, prng);

    my_visitor vis;
    std::vector<default_color_type> colormap(num_vertices(g));
    depth_first_search(g, vis, make_iterator_property_map(colormap.begin(), get(vertex_index, g)));
}
```

Prints

```
initialize_vertex(0, g)
initialize_vertex(1, g)
initialize_vertex(2, g)
initialize_vertex(3, g)
initialize_vertex(4, g)
initialize_vertex(5, g)
initialize_vertex(6, g)
initialize_vertex(7, g)
initialize_vertex(8, g)
initialize_vertex(9, g)
start_vertex(0, g)
discover_vertex(0, g)
examine_edge((0,4), g)
tree_edge((0,4), g)
discover_vertex(4, g)
examine_edge((4,1), g)
tree_edge((4,1), g)
discover_vertex(1, g)
finish_vertex(1, g)
finish_vertex(4, g)
examine_edge((0,9), g)
tree_edge((0,9), g)
discover_vertex(9, g)
examine_edge((9,1), g)
forward_or_cross_edge((9,1), g)
examine_edge((9,2), g)
tree_edge((9,2), g)
discover_vertex(2, g)
finish_vertex(2, g)
examine_edge((9,1), g)
forward_or_cross_edge((9,1), g)
finish_vertex(9, g)
examine_edge((0,1), g)
forward_or_cross_edge((0,1), g)
examine_edge((0,4), g)
forward_or_cross_edge((0,4), g)
examine_edge((0,2), g)
forward_or_cross_edge((0,2), g)
finish_vertex(0, g)
start_vertex(3, g)
discover_vertex(3, g)
examine_edge((3,7), g)
tree_edge((3,7), g)
discover_vertex(7, g)
examine_edge((7,5), g)
tree_edge((7,5), g)
discover_vertex(5, g)
examine_edge((5,1), g)
forward_or_cross_edge((5,1), g)
examine_edge((5,6), g)
tree_edge((5,6), g)
discover_vertex(6, g)
examine_edge((6,1), g)
forward_or_cross_edge((6,1), g)
examine_edge((6,3), g)
back_edge((6,3), g)
examine_edge((6,5), g)
back_edge((6,5), g)
finish_vertex(6, g)
finish_vertex(5, g)
examine_edge((7,6), g)
forward_or_cross_edge((7,6), g)
examine_edge((7,8), g)
tree_edge((7,8), g)
discover_vertex(8, g)
examine_edge((8,3), g)
back_edge((8,3), g)
finish_vertex(8, g)
finish_vertex(7, g)
examine_edge((3,1), g)
forward_or_cross_edge((3,1), g)
finish_vertex(3, g)
```

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't work. If you add - for example - an ``int i`` to your ``MyVertex`` and try to change it from within the DFS-visitor (``g[u].i = 0``), you will get an ``error: assignment of member ‘MyVertex::i’ in read-only object``.

Comment: Well, I was answering the question (which claimed it was passed by copy, which is clearly not the case). But look closely, you have a const graph (because [`depth_first_search` takes a const graph](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/graph/doc/depth_first_search.html)). That makes a lot of sense since modifying the graph is dangerous **and** you should be able to search a const graph. Now, that leaves you with the "inject a non-const reference" approach, make the fields `mutable` or store the properties outside the graph.